# Proper way to install Eric IDE?

Tags: python

As a semi-Python newbie, I tried installing the Eric (6-18.08) IDE on a Windows 7 32-bit host, but it fails:

```
c:\Eric Python IDE>python install.py
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 3.7.0
PyQt5 could not be detected.
Error: No module named 'PyQt5'

Shall 'PyQt5' be installed using pip? (Y/n) Y
Collecting PyQt5
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/44/32c311a6fb23b8b5cc4f
535af1ad65fc3e071440884a1fad3c1aef68f47b/PyQt5-5.11.2-5.11.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38
-none-win32.whl (39.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 39.4MB 264kB/s
Collecting PyQt5_sip<4.20,>=4.19.11 (from PyQt5)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/63/e68c99745d9b95860eb3
48a8bef5d884bcfc966e7b55c866734d1c7a44af/PyQt5_sip-4.19.12-cp37-none-win32.whl (
43kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.3MB/s
Installing collected packages: PyQt5-sip, PyQt5
Successfully installed PyQt5-5.11.2 PyQt5-sip-4.19.12
Found PyQt5
Found pyuic5
QScintilla could not be detected.
Error: cannot import name 'Qsci' from 'PyQt5' (C:\Users\fred\AppData\Local\Progr
ams\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py)

Shall 'QScintilla' be installed using pip? (Y/n) Y
Collecting QScintilla
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/de/389d5c36290e6d62a625
2a7a417681d0a3851f3e373cb63670d06c86806d/QScintilla-2.10.7-5.11.1-cp35.cp36.cp37
.cp38-none-win32.whl (1.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.7MB 1.6MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5>=5.10.1 in c:\users\fred\appdata\local\prog
rams\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from QScintilla) (5.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5_sip<4.20,>=4.19.11 in c:\users\fred\appdata
\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from PyQt5>=5.10.1->QScint
illa) (4.19.12)
Installing collected packages: QScintilla
Successfully installed QScintilla-2.10.7
Found QScintilla2
Found QtGui
Found QtNetwork
Found QtPrintSupport
Found QtSql
Found QtSvg
Found QtWidgets
Sorry, please install PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets or PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets.

Press enter to continue...
```

FYI, it's Python 3.7.0.

Google didn't help. How should I proceed to resume the install?

Thank you.

--

Edit: Does it mean Eric 6 won't install on a 32-bit Windows host?

```
c:\Eric Python IDE>python -m pip install pyqt5==5.10
Collecting pyqt5==5.10
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/84/d4387929385504c020d6
cab193af6cc18fa9fecb8267f76848ea5f76c67d/PyQt5-5.10-5.10.0-cp35.cp36.cp37-none-w
in32.whl (68.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 68.0MB 124kB/s
Collecting sip<4.20,>=4.19.4 (from pyqt5==5.10)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/34/056db01926839dd05f80
a08a579ee2f4f6625913b0620580ee580fa05fbf/sip-4.19.8-cp37-none-win32.whl (42kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.2MB/s
qscintilla 2.10.7 has requirement PyQt5>=5.10.1, but you'll have pyqt5 5.10 whic
h is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: sip, pyqt5
  Found existing installation: PyQt5 5.11.2
    Uninstalling PyQt5-5.11.2:
      Successfully uninstalled PyQt5-5.11.2
Successfully installed pyqt5-5.10 sip-4.19.8

c:\Eric Python IDE>python install.py
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 3.7.0
Found PyQt5
Found pyuic5
QScintilla could not be detected.
Error: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Shall 'QScintilla' be installed using pip? (Y/n) Y
Requirement already satisfied: QScintilla in c:\users\fred\appdata\local\program
s\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (2.10.7)
Collecting PyQt5>=5.10.1 (from QScintilla)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/44/32c311a6fb23b8b5cc4
f535af1ad65fc3e071440884a1fad3c1aef68f47b/PyQt5-5.11.2-5.11.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp3
8-none-win32.whl
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5_sip<4.20,>=4.19.11 in c:\users\fred\appdata
\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from PyQt5>=5.10.1->QScint
illa) (4.19.12)
Installing collected packages: PyQt5
  Found existing installation: PyQt5 5.10
    Uninstalling PyQt5-5.10:
      Successfully uninstalled PyQt5-5.10
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is de
nied: 'C:\\Users\\fred\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-j20b3u70\\users\\fre
d\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pyqt5\\qt\
\bin\\qt5core.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Sorry, please install QScintilla2 and
its PyQt5/PyQt4 wrapper.
Error: QScintilla could not be installed.

Press enter to continue...
```

Comment: 32bits or 64 bits?

Comment: 32.bits. I updated the question.

Comment: The error message is clear, Eric needs QtWebEngineWidgets or QtWebKitWidgets, but those elements are only supported by a 64-bit host, so installation is not necessary since you have 32-bit python installed.

Comment: read: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5 *that for v5.11 and later the 32-bit Windows wheels do not contain the WebEngine modules.*

Comment: A possible solution is to install an old version of PyQt5 using `python -m pip install pyqt5==5.10`and then you just installed eric.

Comment: So… what's a girl to do? Ignore the message, or install an older PyQt5?

Comment: Are you misogynist? What does it have to do to be a girl or boy here?

Comment: The action depends if you are going to use QtWebEngineWidgets or not, if you are not going to use it then continue.

Comment: I don't know what QtWebEngineWidgets is, so I'll just go ahead and pray. Thank you.